# Is it possible to communicate single SPI slave with Two SPI masters

Tags: spi, stm8

I am using two `STM8` micro-controllers as SPI masters. Master-1 is configured in `full duplex` mode. And the Master-2 is configured in `Receive-only` mode. The CS, MISO, MOSI and SCLK lines of Master-1 are connected to the Slave. The CS, MISO and SCLK lines of Master-2 are connected to the Slave. When Master-1 requests data from the slave. Master-1 and Master-2 should receive the data from slave at the same time. And the data should be same. I configured two masters with same baudrate,CPOL and CPHA.

When I am communicating with single master, I could receive the data correctly from the slave. But When I involve the second master in the communication the received data of both master is corrupted. And in the oscilloscope, I could see the SCLK variations on the slave.

What are the things I need to consider while communicating a slave with two masters at the same time.

Comment: The SPI master is the device that drives the SCLK line. You can't have two devices driving the same SCLK line at the same time. As simple as that. I think you have to take a step back and rethink your architecture. Or tell us the bigger picture of what you're trying to do, so we can give advice on that too.

Comment: I am trying to get the data from the slave to two masters at the same time, but only one master should request the slave. When Slave responds to the request two masters should be able to read the data.

Comment: Then, Master-2 shouldn't be a master. It's not initiating the communication, and it shouldn't drive SCLK. It could simply be another slave on the same bus (maybe with a few tricks if it needs to spy both MISO and MOSI).

Comment: Why can't you just configure the 2nd master as a slave thus there will be no clock fights.

Comment: If I make Master-2 as slave, then could I get the same data what I receive on the Master-1 at the same time.

Comment: Look at what Brhan suggests. BUT you need to give a far more complete desription of wht you are trying to achieve and why and what else you do on the SPI lines. What brhans suggests AY work but also configures the 2nd master in a non std mode. If you wish to do other SPI activities his system may be difficult to recnfigure. What data rate do you want to achieve? , why 1-> 2 simultaneously.Give us the bigger picture.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon As you suggested, I redesigned the architecture with Brhan's architecture. Now Master-1 and Now Slave-2(Old Master-1) are receiving data frames from Slave-1. But in **Slave-2** sometimes frames are missing. It is not receiving as expected, this scenario is occurring when I am accessing other peripherals like UART. I could see **BUSY** flag and **OVERRUN ERROR** in Slave-2's SPI. What could be the reason?

Comment: @AbdulGafoor  If your system needs flow control to limit data rate slave-2 may be trying to control flow rate but not be able. What happens if you slow data rate for test purposes? Does error rate drop as data rate drops? Is there a rate at which you get no errors? What % of time is the SPI interface handling data actively. eg if << 50% of the time you could use two sessions. Either M->Sa, M-> S2 , or M->S1, S2 as M to S2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have already said in the comments to your question - you can't simultaneously have 2 masters on an SPI bus. It just doesn't work that way.
But the setup you describe (ignoring your master/slave terminology) could work.
Only your Master-1 stays being a master. Your existing Slave stays as a slave, and your Master-2 becomes a slave, but you connect its data lines as if it's a master.
So:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuiOd5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your Master-1 will Chip-Select both Slave-1 & New-Slave-2(Old-Master-2) at the same time, and then when Slave-1 sends data out on its MISO, this data will be received by Master-1 on its MISO (as expected), and also by New-Slave-2 on its MOSI.

Comment: As you suggested, I redesigned the architecture. Now Master-1 and Now Slave-2(Old Master-1) are receiving data frames from Slave-1. But in **Slave-2** sometimes frames are missing. It is not receiving as expected, this scenario is occurring when I am accessing other peripherals like UART. I could see **BUSY** flag and **OVERRUN ERROR** in Slave-2's SPI. What could be the reason?

Comment: You should be servicing the SPI in Slave-2 sing interrupts so make sure you read data coming in before the next byte arrives (which would cause an overflow). If you're already using interrupts for SPI, make sure that you have the interrupt priority set high enough that it 'interrupts' UART servicing.